# why does this python version of quick sort has the run time error

Tags: python, recursion

```
def quickSort(x):

    if len(x) <= 1:
        return x
    mid = x[0]
    l = filter(lambda k: k<=mid, x)
    r = filter(lambda k: k>mid, x)
    return quickSort(l)+quickSort(r)

b = [3,2,1,5,4]

quickSort(b)
```

Then I got this error:

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out the partition element from the 2 smaller parts:

```
def quickSort(x):
    if len(x) <= 1:
        return x
    mid = x[0]
    l = filter(lambda k: k<mid, x)
    r = filter(lambda k: k>mid, x)
    return quickSort(l) + [mid] + quickSort(r)
```

Otherwise, you can get infinite recursion because the subproblems don't get any smaller.